# Parse an XML webpage using PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, simplexml

How do I use PHP to parse XML on the web?

Here is the [example XML](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20AskRealtime,%20ChangeinPercent%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22A%22,%22AA%22,%22AAN%22,%22AAP%22,%22AAR%22,%22AAT%22,%22AAV%22,%22AB%22,%22ABB%22,%22ABC%22,%22ABD%22,%22ABG%22,%22ABH%22,%22ABM%22,%22ABR%22,%22ABT%22,%22ABV%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys). How would you get the value of the first "AskRealtime"?

I am aware of SimpleXML. I am looking for the proper code to open the XML webpage, and work with it using SimpleXML.

This suggested code does not succesfully load the page:

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20AskRealtime%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22A%22%2C%22AA%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys");

$price = $xml->results->quote[0]->AskRealtime;

echo $price;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using SimpleXMLElement? It works just like your code but it's constructed differently.

```
$url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20AskRealtime%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22A%22%2C%22AA%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
echo $xml->results->quote[0]->AskRealtime;
```

There are different methods for getting the file contents, even though I doubt it's the problem.

```
/* cURL */
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$contents = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

/* Alternative */
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
```

Can you tell what is the error you get? Or try `var_dump($xml)` and see what it returns.

Comment: Uncaught Error: chrome.tabs can only be used in extension processes. See the content scripts documentation for more details.

Comment: Is there any reason I could access the link from a browser, but not from some php file that tries to open it? Am I overlooking some 'same origin' thing here?

Comment: @DonnyP Can you remove any @-signs from your code and add the upcoming PHP errors to your original question? Also try at least some of the alternative methods I described in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Martti - where do I place the var_dump($xml)?

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**. - load the file in SimpleXML `$xml = @simplexml_load_file($fl)  or die($errorMsg);`where $fl is the file URL and $errorMsg is the error message to display.

**Step 2**. - get a content `$whatever=$xml->results->quote->AskRealtime[0];` Explained: it goes to the XML, then what is named "results", then what is named "quote", then what is named AskRealtime, but the first (index 0) of it.

**And a note**: if, for some reason, you'll have to get something which is named whatever-else (so it has a - in the name), then it works only if you make the code `$xml->{'whatever-else'}`

Comment: Thanks axiomer - but the code does not successfully load the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use some HTTP request library to get the file, e.g.: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php

Then feed the response to SimpleXML.